# MS Access - Finding Average and Joining multiple queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I was given one table to use that was imported from an excel spreadsheet. The Table is a CustomerData table that contains attributes: Age,Income,Gender, Etc.

I was told to write these queries in Access:
Income queries:

a.  For each 5 year incremented customer age group 1 to 5; 6 to 10; 11-15, etc.  produced the average income and display the N (count of that age group)

For this query I wrote this but I know there must be a better way:

```
SELECT Avg(CustomerData.Income) AS Average_Income_of_Age_Groups, Count(CustomerData.Age) AS N_Count
FROM CustomerData
Where (((CustomerData.Age)>5 And (CustomerData.Age)<11))
UNION
SELECT Avg(CustomerData.Income) AS Avg_Income_Of_Ages_10_to_15, Count(CustomerData.Age) AS N_Count
FROM CustomerData
Where (((CustomerData.Age)>10 And (CustomerData.Age)<16))
```

And I kept repeating until I got to age 85.. However this query lacks proper labeling of age groups in the result set.

b.  For each 5 year incremented customer age group and gender M, F, produce the average income and display the N (count of that age gender group)

I just started writing this but I am lost... So far I have something like this that will return the average income for males or females in a certain age group:

```
SELECT Avg(Income) AS Average_Income,
   (Select Count (*)
    From CustomerData
    Where Gender = "M" And Age Between 5 and 20) AS Gender_Male
FROM CustomerData
WHERE Age Between 5 and 20 And Gender = "M";
```

c.  For each 5 year incremented customer age group and gender 1 to 5; 6 to 10; 11-15, etc. produce the average income per member of household (Members Within Household/Income)

Please if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For part C could you clarify please? If you are reporting income for each household member, an average income would only need to be used if the person has more than one source of income... which isn't typically the case, so a simple select of their income would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

A)

```
SELECT 
    CStr(([CustomerData].[Age]-[CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5) + 1) & "-" & CStr([CustomerData].[Age]+(5-([CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5))) AS AgeRange
    ,Avg(CustomerData.Income) AS AvgOfIncome
    ,Count(*) AS NumberOfCustomers
FROM 
    CustomerData
GROUP BY 
    CStr(([CustomerData].[Age]-[CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5) + 1) & "-" & CStr([CustomerData].[Age]+(5-([CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5)))
    ,([CustomerData].[Age]-[CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5) + 1
ORDER BY 
    ([CustomerData].[Age]-[CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5) + 1
;
```

B)

```
SELECT 
    CStr(([CustomerData].[Age]-[CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5) + 1) & "-" & CStr([CustomerData].[Age]+(5-([CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5))) AS AgeRange
    ,CustomerData.Gender
    ,Avg(CustomerData.Income) AS AverageIncome
    ,Count(*) AS NumberOfCustomers
FROM 
    CustomerData
GROUP BY 
    CStr(([CustomerData].[Age]-[CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5) + 1) & "-" & CStr([CustomerData].[Age]+(5-([CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5)))
    ,CustomerData.Gender
    ,([CustomerData].[Age]-[CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5) + 1
ORDER BY 
    ([CustomerData].[Age]-[CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5) + 1
;
```

C)

```
SELECT 
    CStr((CustomerData.Age-CustomerData.Age Mod 5) + 1) & "-" & CStr(CustomerData.Age+(5-(CustomerData.Age Mod 5))) AS AgeRange
    ,CustomerData.MembersWithinHousehold
    ,Avg(CustomerData.Income) AS AverageIncome
    ,Count(*) AS NumberOfCustomers
FROM 
    CustomerData
GROUP BY 
    CStr((CustomerData.Age-CustomerData.Age Mod 5) + 1) & "-" & CStr(CustomerData.Age+(5-(CustomerData.Age Mod 5)))
    ,CustomerData.MembersWithinHousehold
    ,(CustomerData.Age-CustomerData.Age Mod 5) + 1
ORDER BY 
    (CustomerData.Age-CustomerData.Age Mod 5) + 1
    ,CustomerData.MembersWithinHousehold 
;
```

## Logic

- `[CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5` -> is using modular division (i.e divide the age by 5 and return the remainder as the answer). We are dividing the customers age by 5 because this is the size you want the age range "buckets" to be. **If someone is 21**, this calc is: `21 mod 5 = 1`. We later subtract this amount from the age to find the start of the age range bucket.
- `([CustomerData].[Age] - [CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5) + 1` -> this finds the start of the age range bucket. So if someone is 21 this calculation is: `(21 - 1) + 1 = 20`
- `5 - ([CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5)` -> this is used to find the end of the age range bucket. Using our 21 year old customer again the calculation is: `5 - (1) = 4`
- `[CustomerData].[Age] + (5 - ([CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5)` -> finds the end of the age range bucket. The calc is: `21 + 4 = 25`
- `CStr(([CustomerData].[Age]-[CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5) + 1) & "-" & CStr([CustomerData].[Age]+(5-([CustomerData].[Age] Mod 5))) AS AgeRange` -> This just builds a string that follows the structure for a 21 year old such i.e: `"21 - 25"`
- Now that we've "built" our buckets, the SQL clause `GROUP BY` allows us to perform aggregations (counts, sums, avg, etc) on these groups, hence why the age range calculation is the first item listed after the `GROUP BY` clause.
- The second `GROUP BY` item is there just to allow me to sort the data set on it, in the `ORDER BY` clause. This is just the start of the age range buckets, and is "cheaper" computationally to sort on than the full age range bucket string as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. The first two work great. For C) in the CustomerData table there is an attribute called: MemberswithinHousehold(which lists the # of people in the household). So I would assume I would need to piggyback off of the query in problem B).

Comment: If you have a spare moment is there any way that you could email me and explain to me the logic going on in these queries? I can be reached at crutej@my.easternct.edu

Comment: Have added what I think you mean for C).

Comment: Logic added as requested